# Realizar dos setState (hook-cambio de estado) en una misma función React Native

Tags: android, nodejs, react-native, react-hooks

para empezar no estoy seguro si el título del problema se ajusta del todo a la consulta, pero aqui va el inconveniente.

Estoy realizando un proyecto en React Native (android), en el cual en una determinada pantalla llamada "LecturaMedidorScreen" llamo a una función para obtener la geolocalización del dispositivo. Una vez obtengo la respuesta solicitada, la almaceno en una variable (let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();)

Luego de obtener el objeto "coords" intento realizar los setState mencionados anteriormente de la siguiente manera:
setLectura({...lectura,['coordX']: coords.longitud})
setLectura({...lectura,['coordY']: coords.latitud})
Entonces, luego de realizar el cambio de estado y almacenar otras variables dentro de la variable "lectura", y, una vez presionado un boton que envia los datos al backend, imprimo dicha variable(lectura), y veo que unicamente "setea" el estado del segundo llamado (en este caso coordY -> latitud)

Tengo entendido por documentaciones que leí, que no se puede(o debe) realizar el cambio de estado de esa manera (dos cambios de estado dentro de una misma funcion), pero como estoy empezando autodidacta en React Native y desarrollo movil en general, no tengo idea de como es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Aqui un poco del codigo:

```
const [ lectura, setLectura ] =  useState ({
    medidorID: idMedidor,
    domicilio: domicilio,
    value: 0,
    foto: '',
    foto1: '',
    foto2: '',
    incidencias: selectedValue,
    descripcion: '',
    coordX: '',
    coordY: '',
    fecha: ''
})
  useEffect(() => {

    const handleLatitud = (latitud) => {
        setLectura({...lectura,['coordY']: latitud})
    }
    const handleLongitud = (value) => {
        setLectura({...lectura,['coordX']: value})
    }

    const getCoordenadas = async () => {
        const data = await GetCurrentLocation();
        handleLatitud(data.latitud)
        handleLongitud(data.longitud)
    }

    CheckIfLocationEnabled();
    getCoordenadas()


}, [focus])
```

aqui "focus" es: const focus = useIsFocused();

La funcion getCurrentLocation es:

```
  const GetCurrentLocation = async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert(
        'Permission not granted',
        'Allow the app to use location service.',
        [{ text: 'OK' }],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
    }
    else{
        let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
  
        if (coords) {
            const latitud = coords.latitude
            const longitud = coords.longitude
           
            //handleLatitud(latitud)
            //handleLongitud(coords.longitude)

            const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
            let response = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
                latitude,
                longitude
            });
            
      
            for (let item of response) {
                let address = `${item.name}, ${item.street}, ${item.postalCode}, ${item.city}`;                  
            }
            return {latitud: latitud, longitud:longitud}
        }
        
    } 
  };
```

Como verán dentro de dicha función esta comentado nuevamente el handleLongitud y HandleLatitud debido a que el resultado era el mismo, "seteaba" unicamente la ultima instrucción. (Por supuesto que cuando dichas lineas no se encontraban comentadas, la declaración de las funciones se encontraba donde corresponden y no dentro del "useEffect")

Bueno, es mi primer post asi que si se requiere de información extra avisen, estaré pendiente.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

sepan disculpar pero les queria comentar que encontre la solución y la comparto acá por si alguien tiene el mismo inconveniente.

cambie las lineas (dentro de la funcion "GetCurrentLocation") :
setLectura({...lectura,['coordY']: latitud})
setLectura({...lectura,['coordX']: longitud})
por:
setLectura({...lectura,['coordX']:longitud, ['coordY']: latitud})

el useEffect quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    CheckIfLocationEnabled();
    GetCurrentLocation(); 
}, [focus])
```

y luego las funciones "handleLatitud" y "handleLongitud" las elimine.
Listo eso fue todo.